# How to make ng2-bootstrap popover doesn't get dismiss on mouseover popover container?

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

Using Angular 2 and ngx-bootstrap, I'm trying to ensure that the popover doesn't get dismissed if the mouse is either on the target element or over the popover container. I tried to subscribe to the onShown EventEmitter and add the mouseeneter listener event on the content elementRef, but I can't seem to make it work. Is there a way to add triggers to the popover content?

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.popover.onShown.subscribe(next => {
      this.showListener = this.renderer.listen(next.content.elementRef.nativeElement, 'mouseenter', this.popover.show);
      this.hideListener = this.renderer.listen(next.content.elementRef.nativeElement, 'mouseleave', this.popover.hide);
    });
  }

  @HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event']) onMouseEnter($event: Event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    this.popover.show();
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave', ['$event']) onMouseLeave($event: Event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    this.popover.hide();
  }
```